# React-leaflet: How to reset the style?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet, choropleth, react-leaflet-v3

I am trying to reset the styles when I the mouse out event is triggered. But it is giving a error. this is working perfectly fine when I am using react-leaflet 2.8.0. But dont know why its causing an issue now.

```
geoJsonRef.current.leafletElement.resetStyle(e.target);
```

[Link to the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sky-gsqs5c?file=/src/mapUtils.js)

Comment: the demo does not reproduce the issue. There are errors

Comment: sorry for that. can u take a look now. I commented out the code of reset. it is in maputils 47th line. I also dont think that getbounds is working properly